# Weighted-average distance to weighted-mean vector - how to maximise?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

### Weighted-average distance to weighted-average point

Suppose we are given two or more n-dimensional unit vectors $u_i$ (for some norm) and, associated to each, a weight $m_i$.

Now take the weighted mean vector (somewhere in the unit ball, in the interior except for special cases)

$$
\mu := \frac {\sum_i m_i u_i} {\sum_i m_i}
$$

and now the quantity

$$
M := \frac {\sum_i m_i ||u_i - \mu||} {\sum_i m_i}
$$

i.e. the weighted-average norm distance to the weighted-average point. (The norm is the same norm by which the original vectors $u_i$ are units.)

### Maximising it

What is the maximum of the quantity $M$? What configurations maximise it?

My intuition (and a few million random samples in $L^2$!) suggest that this is maximised whenever $\mu = \mathbf 0$, so then the average distance is $M = 1$.

Can we prove this, or is there a counterexample? Do we need to assume anything about the norm (e.g. strict convexity)?

---

Trivially $M \le 2$ by considering the triangle inequality of the norm distances with $\mathbf 0$ but intuitively and in practice this is a poor bound because it neglects that $\mu$ *far* from $u_i$ means $m_i$ carries less weight.

If we could constrain $\mu$ to be collinear with each $u_i$ at a maximum, this would be sufficient (because any two linearly independent $u_i$ would force $\mu = \mathbf 0$).

Alternatively, perhaps exploiting a triangle inequality decomposing the terms of $\mu$ could yield a proof - in particular, $u_i$'s distance to the $u_i$ component of $\mu$ is of course zero! - but I've not had success with this approach.